# How to change PATH of VirtualBox images

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, path

I have **some** virtual machines on external drive (have local ones too so I can't just change the path in GUI).
I moved the folder with virt. machines again.

```
Before: /Volumes/6TB_encrypted/only_here/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/
After:  /Volumes/6TB_encrypted/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/
```

How to change the path in VirtualBox without unregistering and re-registering the images (machines), or removing and opening .vbox files one by one? Don't want symlinks.

I did not find command line option to change the path.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the [Global Settings](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#vboxconfigdata-global) config file which is located here:

- Linux and Oracle Solaris: `$HOME/.config/VirtualBox`
- Windows: `$HOME/.VirtualBox`
- Mac OS X: `$HOME/Library/VirtualBox`

Find `<MachineRegistry>` tag and remove the `only_here/` from the src attributes. VirtualBox must not be running.

```
<MachineRegistry>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{83c316ae-4bcf-40f7-901e-da4ba7958b6c}" src="/Volumes/6TB_encrypted/only_here/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/centos7/centos7.vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{833b3593-c200-4042-8b49-c583e64cc000}" src="/Volumes/6TB_encrypted/only_here/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/Ubuntu......vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{732c0bd1-9d83-4fe1-bda0-239a1c06929d}" src="/Volumes/6TB_encrypted/only_here/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/centos......vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{f8c6792a-6610-49c4-8d94-71147deb0a88}" src="/Volumes/6TB_encrypted/only_here/VIRTUAL_HOSTS/Ubuntu......vbox"/>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{90154b7b-ab87-44ad-a83f-7a9e18ed0e72}" src="/Users/ad/VirtualBox VMs/tails/tails.vbox"/>
</MachineRegistry>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows when all the machines were powered off I had moved

```
"%USERPROFILE%\VirtualBox VMs" to "Y:\VirtualBox VMs"
```

After making sure all the VM services were not running I edited

```
"%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml"
```

Changing the old location to the new.
Restarted the services and was able to power up the machines without any issues.
I also changed where new machines would be created in the VirtualBox Manager under -> File -> Preferences -> General